# download files using document extension iOS

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, uidocumentpickervc

Can we download and upload files from server using document extension in iOS ? I read there is a method `documentStorageURL , originalURL` in UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController class. 
    But in my case I have a  C++ SDK that downloads a file from a server. So it is possible to integrate a SDK in the extension target of my application and use the SDK to download the file from another third party application. 
    Has anyone tried to download a file via iOS NSURLSession or NSURLConnection classes in a UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController class? or is their any limitations for extension not being able to integrate normal iOS app functionality ?  Any sample code or references will be great.

Comment: have you ever figured this out, I have a similar problem